# cleaning up dead questions

Tags: discussion

I ask this in the interest of maintaining high-quality content on SQA: should we do anything in particular about questions like [Selenium tests aren´t launched anymore](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/selenium-tests-arent-launched-anymore), i.e. questions that do not provide enough detail for a valuable answer, which have been around for several months, and which the Community daemon (or whatever that process is called) periodically moves back to the top of the Questions list?

Answer (score 2):

I learnt (the hard way) that a mod can't vote to close ... we just close ... maybe we should plan an unanswered question cleanup ...

Answer (score 1):

There are mechanisms available to the SQA community to close down questions that don't give enough information for a useful answer to be provided, but it's quite rare in my experience for anyone to vote to close a question.

I'm not sure why this is, or how to improve it - but this would be one good way of cleaning out the dead questions. I don't vote to close anything myself until someone else has already done so, as being a moderator, my vote is a closing vote and as such I usually only feel comfortable with making that vote when the community have already expressed an opinion.