# How do we clean up low quality questions?

Tags: discussion

Is anyone tracking the signal to noise (high-quality to low-quality) ratio for SQA questions?  My sense is it's going down; there seem to be a lot of "help me with my homework" and "save me from searching Google for the answer" and "please tell me how to do my job by answering this broad question" kind of questions.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of any concerted effort of quality control. I do know our "answered" ratio is currently at 86%, which is lower than it usually is. The number one cause of a low answered ratio is poor quality questions that go unclosed.

The easiest way to fix this is to clean up poor questions. Edit them so someone can answer them, answer them ourselves, upvote good answers on "unanswered" questions (questions that have low-vote answers are considered unanswered) are ways to salvage a good question. The not good questions simply need to be closed.

To close questions, we need two areas of attack. One area is to seek out the poor questions (the easiest of which is the [Unanswered tab](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered)). The second area is the [Closed Vote queue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/review/close/6179) to tackle the ones identified by the seeker with the four additional close votes.

We're currently at 382 unanswered questions. We're also almost exactly two years after [the last time user246 brought this up](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/cleaning-up-dead-questions?rq=1) and it looks like we're not much further along, notably because no post cleanup effort was ever officially organized.

Do we collectively have time for a concerted effort to clean up the old posts? I guess that depends on what we're looking at for time. 382 questions would be roughly 20 hours (if we include the closers as well as the seekers) of work to properly identify and close all the poor questions. Of course, that means skipping salvagable or answerable questions instead of editing or answering them. It's also incredibly boring work to do (probably why it hasn't been done in a while). If it was spread out over a couple weeks it could probably get done. We'd want to keep track of progress to prevent duplication. We could either use comments on a meta post, or we could use the SQA chat room to keep track of that.

Comment: Chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22957/sqa-cleanup

Comment: This post reminded me to choose answers for questions I asked in the past. I hope ratio will now be better ;-)

Comment: I just did the same thing.

Comment: We've cleaned up over 50 unanswered questions in two weeks! That's pretty good!

Comment: As I got from the Question and Answers of this post, we might need to train users of this community too (informing them time to time), mandatory site Tour, etc. this will help in improving the quality of the questions being asked and also users will not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score -1):

This is most popular sharing community.Anyone can can share his own question.

Different quality members are present. One user's share question is to be easy for another users. It's not mean that this is low quality question.

Suggestion:-- You can categories these question type
               1. Recent Question 2. Recent Answered 3.Most Viewed 4. Most vote

- If any question, any answer is not given more than 15 or 30 days  then you can send one reminder to question owner. After that if any changes is not done in question then removed this question.

Comment: This is not about naive questions, Ranjit.  It is about questions are too broad,  or too opinion-based, or too ambiguous to answer because the author left out important details, e.g. asking for help with a Selenium problem but neglecting to show the code or the HTML.

Comment: I have to mostly agree with user246. There are definitely a lot of unanswered questions that are not low quality - and we should answer those if we can, promote them if we can, etc. But say someone joins and wants to help answer unanswered questions. How can they if they have to wade through 10 low quality questions before they find a good one they can answer? Chances are they leave after 2 or 3 low quality questions instead. And that's bad.