# Closing Dead Questions

Tags: discussion

I was digging through Unanswered Questions today and have noticed several questions where users have requested more information in order to be able to answer them and no response from the OP.

This topic had been covered previously [here](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/cleaning-up-dead-questions/174#174) but I am not seeing any clear reason for closing a question due to inactivity. There is unclear what they are asking, but it is clear. They simply are not providing enough data to answer their extremely specific question.

A few examples:

[Request for More Data](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/selenium-webdriver-spicejet-website-automation)

[Request for more Data](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17969/unable-to-locate-element-on-win-7-safari-browser-using-selenium)

[Slightly older one](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16383/appium-getting-stuck-at-tapping-on-buttons-under-a-loop)

I think providing some time to answer these requests for more information (1 - 4 weeks) would be great but getting the question to where it could be answerable or closed/deleted would be great for the community as a whole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with that, and I don't know why we would wait more than four weeks.

I think "unclear what you're asking" is the best available choice.

Comment: Is there a suitable reason for a close vote that would be best for these scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with that. Unanswered questions should be deleted or moved to a more appropriate forum so it can receive proper answers.

But for the question where people have asked for more feedback or info and haven't received, I guess 4 weeks time is more than enough for them. After that such question should be deleted. Clearly the person who asked the question isn't interested enough to get an asnwer anyway. Deleting such answers will also mean that the site will have better data for people looking for help. Sometimes such dead question line up in a search result and the user may go away from the site.